# Would lucid dreaming be an effective weapon against Freddy Krueger?

Tags: freddy-krueger

Considering that the **Nightmare on Elm Street** antagonist kills via generating fear in ones dreams, then using that fear to power his attacks, would the ability to control one's dreams (lucid dreaming) be an effective weapon *against* his abilities?

What about drugs that suppress fear? No fear, no power, and possibility no way for him to weaponize it against you. Besides that, we tend to think more clearly when unafraid.

Would Freddy be able to terrorize someone who is chemically *unable* to fear terror?

Comment: Did they not utilize a form of lucid dreaming (hypnosis) to stalk and fight Freddie in the 3rd movie, Dream Warriors? As far as I know, there are no drugs that suppress fear.

Comment: This was literally the plot of Dream Warriors. It was moderately successful albeit nearly got them all killed.

Answer (score 5):

In the 3rd movie, a group of kids at an asylum actually band together to fight Freddy by taking control of their dreams. The problem with this was, Freddy's powers were too great for them to fight alone. He has been king of the castle (he keeps the souls of those he kills) long enough that their "power" couldn't keep up, and he ultimately kills everyone other than the main hero (if memory serves).

She managed to beat him by combining everyone's "power". And if i'm not mixing up movies, she manages to release the souls of those he's slain.

It also seems to me that Freddy can instill fear into someone who might not be able to feel fear. Also, he doesn't just need the person to be afraid, he needs a collection of people to have a fear of him (*Freddy VS Jason*: shadow Freddy fails to kill until he's strong enough). So even a lack of fear by one, can still get you killed if he's in your dream.

Comment: You are combining a few movies together (mostly 3 & 4 - e.g. several people die in 3, but 2 of them (beyond the heroine) continue on and are pulled into a dream in the beginning of 4) but the details a still pretty good :)